# how to make the following scala immutable

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

Suppose I have the following code:

BroadcastMessage gets a list of groups of students in the form of iterators **that can only be traversed once**
On call to `sendMessage` it will send message to all students in the groups.

```
class BroadcastMessage(message:String,groups:List[Iterator[Student]]) {

  def sendMessage:Unit = {
      groups.foreach(group=>group.foreach(sendeMessage))
  }

  private def sendMessage(student:Student): Unit ={
    EmailClient.sendMessage(student.email,message)
  }

}

case class Student(id: String,email:String)
```

Say that student can exist in several groups and we **don't** want to send him more than one email.

The mutable solution would be to add mutable set and to add the id of the student to the set and only send the message if the id exists in the set.

```
class BroadcastMessage(message:String,groups:List[Iterator[Student]]) {
  // evil mutable set
  private var set:scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set()

  def sendMessage:Unit = {
      groups.foreach(group=>group.foreach(sendeMessage))
  }

  private def sendMessage(student:Student): Unit ={
    if (set.add(student.id)) {
      EmailClient.sendMessage(student.email, message)
    }
  }

}
```

How do I implement it in immutable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think that you are making two different mutable things in your example, while you only really need one.

You either need a `private val set : mutable.Set[Student] = mutable.Set.empty[Student]` or a `private var set : Set[Student] = Set.empty[Student]`. That is, you either need to **mutate the set itself** or just the **reference** to it that your class holds. I would personally go for the latter, ending up with something like:

```
case class Student(id: String,email:String)

class BroadcastMessage(message:String,groups:List[Iterator[Student]]) {
  private var set : Set[Student] = Set.empty // <- no mutable Set, just a mutable reference to several immutable Sets

  def sendMessage:Unit = {
    groups.foreach(group=>group.foreach(sendMessage))
  }

  private def sendMessage(student:Student): Unit = {
    if (!set(student)) {
      set = set + student
      EmailClient.sendMessage(student.email, message)
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, you could even get rid of the `sendMessage(student : Student)` method all together:

```
case class Student(id: String,email:String)

class BroadcastMessage(message:String,groups:List[Iterator[Student]]) {
  private var set : Set[Student] = Set.empty

  def sendMessage:Unit = {

    val students = (for{
      group <- groups
      student <- group
    } yield student).toSet

    val toBeNotified = (students -- set)
    toBeNotified.foreach(student => EmailClient.sendMessage(student.email, message))

    set = set ++ toBeNotified
  }
}
```

I guess it depends on style then...

Comment: nice. what do you think about my solution?

Comment: But I see that in your seconds solution you traverse over each item twice... which I cannot do. ( I know in the example it seems ok but in my real code the Student iterator is actually file reader).

Comment: I think it works ok, but I thought that you needed the set because, if your method was called multiple times, you would not want to notify students again. If that is the case, then your solution is delegating the responsibility of tracking that to the caller of the method. If that is ok with you, then great. :)

Comment: I don't think I am iterating over the Iterator twice...I do go through the internal Set twice, but each iterator is scanned only once, `student <- group`

Comment: You have a good point. I wish I can make things a bit more stateless, though (not having the `var`).

Comment: Just a note, this is not an immutable way. You have a changing constant (set of students) that is when called in multi-threaded environment will change randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do do this. I think I lost some readability but it is mutable:

```
class BroadcastMessage(message: String, groups: List[Iterator[Student]]) {

  def sendMessage(): Unit = {
    groups.foldLeft[Set[String]](Set.empty)(sendMessage)
  }

  private def sendMessage(sent: Set[String], group: Iterator[Student]):Set[String] = {
    group.foldLeft[Set[String]](sent)(sendMessage)
  }

  private def sendMessage(sent: Set[String], student: Student): Set[String] = {
    if (!sent.contains(student.id)) {
      EmailClient.sendMessage(student.email, message)
      return sent + student.id
    }
    sent
  }

}
```

Comment: as @mdm mentioned correctly - in this solution I'm delegating responsibility of not sending same email twice to the caller method... which I seems worse than having a `var`...

Answer (score 0):

If you have no memory restrictions, you can just do this:

```
def sendMessage:Unit = {
    groups.flatten.distinct.foreach(sendMessage)
}
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants that, if the method is called again, the same `students` are not sent a new message.

Comment: In the example I don't have memory restrictions but I do have it in my real code. The students iterator is actually a stream of files.

Comment: You can use Stream and it also has 'distinct' operation, and that way you would not have any memory problems

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a one-liner:

```scala
def sendMessage: Unit = 
  groups.reduce(_ ++ _).toStream.distinct.foreach(sendMessage)
```

---

Expanded version for learning purpose:

```scala
val students: Iterator[Student] = groups.reduce(_ ++ _)
val sStudents: Stream[Student] = students.toStream
val dStudents: Stream[Student] = sStudents.distinct
def sendMessage: Unit = sStudents.foreach(sendMessage)
```

Comment: Looks cool - how many times do I traverse on each Student object here? what happens if student is registered with same id but different emails?

Comment: If you want to distinct `Student`s using their `id`s, you should override `==` and `hashCode`of `Student`. Is `Student` a case class?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is all unique `Student`s in the nested collection.

A very simple way to do this is by flattening the collection and converting it to a `Set`; here is an example with `Int`s:

```
scala> val groups = List(Iterator(1,2,3), Iterator(3,4,5))
groups: List[Iterator[Int]] = List(non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator)

scala> val unique: Set[Int] = groups.flatten.toSet
unique: Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

A problem here is that the `toSet` methods actually copies your list. To avoid this, you can use this little trick (you can read more about `collection.breakOut` and `CanBuildFrom` [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout)):

```
scala> val unique: Set[Int] = groups.flatMap(identity)(collection.breakOut)
unique: Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

However, the source of mutability here is the usage of an `Iterator` which will be consumed anyway, there mutating and breaking [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).